# How do I make a dice roll with the option to tell how many throws you want to do

Tags: c#, dice

I am new to programming and I have a task tomorrow. I have to make a dice where the "Thrower" is going to choose how many rolls they want to throw. I know the random function a little bit but how am I going to make the number of throws to be executed with the random function. I have tried different

Comment: 1.  Ask User how many times.  2. Convert to integer.  3. Loop that many times.  4. Profit!

Comment: Make sure you use the same instance of `Random` for all the rolls/throws. Don't create a new one each time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming this is schoolwork, so I won't give you everything. This should get you what you need, but you'll have to handle errors like invalid input and moving this into a function if that is required.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter number of throws:");
    string numThrows = Console.ReadLine();

    Random rnd = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt32(numThrows); i++)
    {
        int dice_number = rnd.Next(1, 7);
        Console.WriteLine("Dice result: " + dice_number);
    }
}
```

`Console.ReadLine` is how you get user input.

The `Random` class allows you to generate random numbers, it's best to reuse a single instance rather than create new ones, so it is created outside of the `for` loop.

Loop to the inputted number of throws. `.Next(1, 7)` limits this to a six sided dice.

Write the results to the console.